# Focusable composite in SWT

Tags: eclipse, swt

We have a custom control that is essentially a composite with label and a button. Currently when the user presses "Tab" the focus comes to the button.

How can I make the composite to receive focus and the button to be excluded from the focus? E.g. the user should be able to tab through all custom controls and not stop at buttons.

**Updated:** Our controls tree looks like this:

- Main pane

  - CustomPanel1

    - Label
    - Button
  - CustomPanel2

    - Label
    - Button
  - CustomPanel3

    - Label
    - Button

All CustomPanel's are of the same Composite subclass. What we need is for the tab to cycle between those panels and do not "see" buttons (those are the only focusable components)

Comment: What's the benefit of this approach? When the user tabs to the next `Composite`, what will he/she be able to do without focusing a `Widget`?

Comment: @Baz We will show some data in another component and accept keyboard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the tab order of a `Composite` by using [`Composite#setTabList(Control[])`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html#setTabList%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control%5b%5d%29).

Here is a small example that will tab between the `Button`s `one` and `three` ignoring the `Button`s `two` and `four`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite content = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    content.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Button one = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
    one.setText("One");

    final Button two = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
    two.setText("Two");

    final Button three = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
    three.setText("Three");

    final Button four = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
    four.setText("Four");

    Control[] controls = new Control[] {one, three};

    content.setTabList(controls);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

**EDIT**: The code above can easily be converted to fit your requirements. I can't test it myself, because `Composite`s aren't focus-able, but you should get the idea:

```
mainPane.setTabList(new Control[] {customPanel1, customPanel2, customPanel3 });

customPanel1.setTabList(new Control[] {});
customPanel2.setTabList(new Control[] {});
customPanel3.setTabList(new Control[] {});
```

Comment: Please see my update - hopefully this will clear up our requirements.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I've gotten back to that module and was able to play with this functionality - basically, I need to be really careful when overriding setFocus in my composites.