# Focusing on a composite when tabbing through children?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have developed a custom component that needs to gain focus when I tab through a main `Composite`. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a key listener to the composite so that it can gain focus, using `Control#addKeyListener(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the tab order of a `Composite` by using [`Composite#setTabList(Control[])`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html#setTabList(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control[])).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923814/focusable-composite-in-swt) is an example using this feature.